# How to dynamically adjust the window size in tkinter to "autofit" its contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently working on a GUI using tkinter which allows the user to navigate between different frames. I based my code structure on [this user response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter).

My issue now is to automatically adjust tkinter's window to its contents when a frame is changed. I want the borders of the window to fit the widgets following the red arrows as in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFhJd.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjcPR.png) (the outputs from the sample code below), so that there is no such "empty space" in each frame.

The code works in a way that the method `show_frame` allows the change between the two defined frames.

```
from tkinter import *


class WindowController(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = Frame(root)
        container.grid()

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (FirstWindow, SecondWindow):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(FirstWindow)

        self.destroy()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class FirstWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Widgets:

        # "Do Nothing" Button
        self.Title0 = Button(self, text='Do nothing')
        self.Title0.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # "Do Nothing" Button
        self.Title1 = Button(self, text='Do Nothing')
        self.Title1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Change Frame Button
        self.Title2 = Button(self, text='To Second Window', command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(SecondWindow))
        self.Title2.grid(row=2, column=0)


class SecondWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Widgets:

        # "Do Nothing" Button
        self.Title0 = Button(self, text='Do nothing')
        self.Title0.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # "Do Nothing" Button
        self.Title1 = Button(self, text='Do Nothing')
        self.Title1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Change Frame Button
        self.Title2 = Button(self, text='To First Window', command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(FirstWindow))
        self.Title2.grid(row=0, column=2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app = WindowController()
    app.mainloop()
```

My problem seems to be similar to the one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212948/dynamically-fit-tkinter-window-to-its-content), but it wasn't solved.

This is my first question here, so criticism is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question [Tkinter Frame Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991126/tkinter-frame-resize): Since both frames are gridded the window will expand to contain them both.

To get the window to change size you need to have only one frame gridded at a time.

To remove a frame from a window and still remember its attributes use:

```
frame.grid_remove()
```

To display the frame again use:

```
frame.grid()  # Will remember grid settings
```

This code works but you could probably improve on its beauty:

```
class WindowController(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(root)
        container.grid()
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (FirstWindow, SecondWindow):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.grid_remove()     # Remove all frames

        self.show_frame(FirstWindow)
        self.destroy()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        for fme in self.frames:     # Remove all frames
            self.frames[fme].grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.grid()        # Display frame
```

Comment: that works for me, and I understand the issue now. Thank you so much for the response.